# Java 8 - Returning an empty Optional

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I have this method that I want to return an empty optional is nothing is found

```
@Override
public Optional<Menu> findBySymbol (String symbol) {
    Optional<Menu> menu = 
                    StreamSupport
                    .stream(cachedMenus.get(ALL_CURRENCIES_KEY).spliterator(), true)
                    .findFirst();

    return menu.orElse(Optional.empty());

}
```

but I got a compilation error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Optional<Object> to Menu`

Comment: Just return the first expression, delete the last line. It does nothing of any use. But the entire method seems overkill - why create a `Stream` just to take the first item?

Comment: Why creating a parallel stream to return the first item? Maybe you meant `findAny()`?

Comment: By the way, why do you even have that `symbol` as an argument to the method? It's currently unused!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

why not just return it?

```
return StreamSupport.stream(cachedMenus.get(ALL_CURRENCIES_KEY).spliterator(), true)
                     .findFirst();
```

Answer (score 5):

just return:

```
return StreamSupport.stream(cachedMenus.get(ALL_CURRENCIES_KEY).spliterator(), true)
                    .findFirst();
```

this will return the first element wrapped in an Optional or empty Optional if the source is empty.

Answer (score 5):

`Optional.orElse(T other)` returns the value if presents, otherwise the parameter is returned as value.
So the compiler expects as parameter type a variable with the same type as the generic used for the `Optional`.   Here you have a `Optional<Menu>`, so a `Menu` is expected.
Whereas the compilation error here :

```
return menu.orElse(Optional.empty());
```

Note that the main purpose of `Optional` is indeed to wrap the value if exits or to wrap empty (instead of `null`).
So to get an empty optional from a stream processing such as `findFirst()` or `findAny()`, you  don't need to do anything.
So as others said, that is enough :

```
return  StreamSupport
        .stream(cachedMenus.get(ALL_CURRENCIES_KEY).spliterator(), true)
        .findFirst();
```